# Programmatic search on custom formatted column in jQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

I'm trying to do a programmatic search on a custom formatted column in jQGrid, but it's not working. Here's my code. I just compiled this code from different internet sources, so don't get me wrong if you someone finds pieces of code they wrote.

In the snippet below, the custom formatted column is the `delCol`, but searching with the column doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function () {            

        var mydata = [
                { id: "1", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Tom" },
                { id: "2", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "Jerry" },
                { id: "3", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Dog" },
                { id: "4", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Cat" },
                { id: "5", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "Mouse" },
                { id: "6", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Keller" },
                { id: "7", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Jekyll" },
                { id: "8", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "Hyde" },
                { id: "9", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Superman" },
                { id: "10", invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Spiderman" },
                { id: "11", invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "He-man" },
                { id: "12", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Cat" },
                { id: "13", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Bat" },
                { id: "14", invdate: "2007-10-05", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "Rat" },
                { id: "15", invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Pat" },
                { id: "16", invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test", note: "note", amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", total: "210.00", custText: "Gate" },
                { id: "17", invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test2", note: "note2", amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", total: "320.00", custText: "Claw" },
                { id: "18", invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3", note: "note3", amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", total: "430.00", custText: "Jerry" }
            ],
            getColumnIndexByName = function (grid, columnName) {
                var cm = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel');
                for (var i = 0, l = cm.length; i < l; i++) {
                    if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                        return i; // return the index
                    }
                }
                return -1;
            },
            grid = $('#list'), firstButtonColumnIndex, buttonNames = {};

        grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            loadonce: true,
            datatype: 'local',
            colNames: ['Inv No', 'Date', 'Client', 'Amount', 'Tax', 'Total', 'Notes', 'Custom'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', index: 'id', key: true, width: 70, sorttype: "int" },
                { name: 'invdate', index: 'invdate', width: 90, sorttype: "date" },
                { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 100 },
                { name: 'amount', index: 'amount', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'tax', index: 'tax', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'total', index: 'total', width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" },
                { name: 'note', index: 'note', width: 100, sortable: true },
                { name: 'delCol', width: 70, sortable: true, index: 'custText',search:true,
                    formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
                        return "<img src='/gr_focus.gif'/><span>" + rowObject.custText + "</span>"
                    },
                    unformat: function (cellvalue, options, cell) {
                        return cellvalue;
                    }
                }
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],             
            viewrecords: true,
            gridview: true,
            height: '100%',
            rownumbers: true,
            caption: 'How to select columns',
            beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
                var iCol = $.jgrid.getCellIndex(e.target);
                if (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) {
                    alert("rowid=" + rowid + "\nButton name: " + buttonNames[iCol]);
                }

                // prevent row selection if one click on the button
                return (iCol >= firstButtonColumnIndex) ? false : true;
            } 
        });
        firstButtonColumnIndex = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'add');
        buttonNames[firstButtonColumnIndex] = 'Add';
        buttonNames[firstButtonColumnIndex + 1] = 'Edit';
        buttonNames[firstButtonColumnIndex + 2] = 'Remove';
        buttonNames[firstButtonColumnIndex + 3] = 'Details';
        grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
    });

 function searchGridFn() {
    grid = $("#list");
    var searchFiler = $("#filter").val(), f;

    if (searchFiler.length === 0) {
        grid[0].p.search = false;
        $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: "" });
    }
    f = { groupOp: "OR", rules: [] };
    f.rules.push({ field: "name", op: "cn", data: searchFiler });
    f.rules.push({ field: "delCol", op: "cn", data: searchFiler });
    grid[0].p.search = true;
    $.extend(grid[0].p.postData, { filters: JSON.stringify(f) });
    grid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1, current: true}]);

}

<table id="list">
</table>
<div id="pager">
</div>
<br />
<fieldset style="float: left">
    <input id="filter" />
    <button id="searchButton" onclick="searchGridFn()">
        Search</button>
</fieldset>
<br />
<br />
<button style="clear: left" id="sortGridButton" onclick="sortGridFn()">
    Sort Grid</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalFilter.htm) where I use the code which you posted do work. Just type `3` or  `2` in the input field and click on "Search" button. You will see the filtered items in the grid.

By the way you use `"delCol"` in the filter which not exist in `colModel` so the filtering can be done only by content of `"name"` column.

**UPDATED**: If you use `datatype: 'local'` (or if you use `datatype: 'json'` or `datatype: 'xml'` together with `loadonce: true`) you **have to** use values of `index` property of `colModel` the same as the value of `name` property. I recommend you don't specify `index` property of `colModel`. In the case the value of `index` property will be copied from `name` property internally.

So what you should do is

- change `name: 'delCol'` to `name: 'custText'` which corresponds to input data which you use.
- (optionally) remove all `index` properties from `colModel`.
- use `"custText"` instead of `"delCol"` during building the filter (use `f.rules.push({ field: "custText", op: "cn", data: searchFiler });`).

Comment: I'm trying to filter by the delCol column, which is the custom formatted column. The `delCol` does exist in the colModel.`name: 'delCol', width: 70, sortable: true, index...`

Comment: @Siddharth: you should better never use `index` property of `colModel` if you use `datatype: "local"` the value **must be** the same as the value `name` property. I updated the code of the demo.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, ur suggestion works. I believe the catch here is to use the same names for the `name` and the `index` properties.

Comment: @Siddharth: You are welcome! I recommend you don't use `index` properties at all. Only if you use `datatype: 'json'` or `datatype: 'xml'` **without** loadonce: true then you can specify `index` properties other as `name`. Only for such columns which have values **other** as `name` you should specify `index` property.

Comment: @Siddharth: I see that you never used your voting right. It's **very important** for stackoverflow because voting is the main criteria used by searching engine. *The users* having more as 15 reputation points decide which answers or questions are **helpful**. The answers with 0 (or low) voting could be typically not found. So by usage of voting you **helps other users to find helpful information on the stackoverflow**. You have right to vote up to 30 time **per day** (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5213/147495)).

Comment: @Siddharth: So I recommend you to vote all questions or answers which you find on the stackoverflow and which you *personally* find **helpful**. You need just click on "arrow up" button on the left of the answer or question.